# Why prefer monoids over semigroups in Haskell? Why do we need mempty?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, category-theory

I can understand the reason for mappend and associativity requirement for it. But why do we need the identity element what is the pragmatic usefulness in it? Or maybe I've missed something important and without definition of it in instances the whole logic won't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `mempty` certainly is needed for some applications. For instance, what should be the result of [`foldMap`ping](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldMap) over an empty list? There's no `a` value you could feed the mapped function to obtain an `m`. So, there needs to be a “default”. It's nice if this is an identity element of an associative operation – for example it allows arbitrary reordering/chunking the fold without changing the result. When folding over a tree, actually a lot of `mempty`s may show up in the middle but you always know they will get “squeezed out” in the end result, so you don't depend on the exact tree layout for reproducable results.

That said, you're right with your concern: `Semigroup` would quite often be sufficient, and it would probably be better if this class were used wherever `mempty` isn't needed (since there are actually a few quite nifty types that are `Semigroup` but not `Monoid`). However, the early design of the standard library apparently did not consider this important enough to warrant the extra class, so lots of code came to rely on `Monoid` without really needing a monoid.

So – much the same issue as we used to have with `Monad`: lots of code really only needed `Applicative` or even just `Functor`, but for historical reasons was stuck with `Monad` anyway until the AMP. Ultimately the problem is that Haskell class hierarchies can't really be *refined* after the fact, only extended *downwards*, not upwards.

Comment: It seems a bit sad that AMP didn't go so far as to insert some of Kmett's classes. Once you start talking about semigroups, you ultimately find yourself wanting `Apply`, `Alt`, `Bind`, `Semigroupoid`, `Foldable1`, and `Traversable1` (I think those names are right).

Comment: @dfeuer Having messed around with PureScript a bit, which went all-in on the `Semigroupoid` family in the design of its library, I personally find those classes to not really be worth their weight for practical use. When you're smashing things together it's useful to have something to smash them into!

Answer (score 5):

These days `base` features classes for both `Semigroup` and `Monoid` (and plans are afoot to make the latter imply the former), so you don't have to choose between the two abstractions - just use the weakest assumption suitable for your purpose.

That said, `Monoid` does seem to be somewhat more useful in daily practice than `Semigroup`. Why is this? I can think of a couple of lines of argument:

1. Things that are useful in programming, such as collections, tend to have zero-or-many semantics; `Monoid` naturally abstracts composable collections of things in a way that `Semigroup` doesn't. (For example, `[]`, the *free* `Monoid`, is a classic example of a collection.)
2. Types that are `Semigroup`s but not `Monoid`s tend to lose precision when you start composing them. Given two non-empty lists `xs` and `ys`, we know that `xs <> ys` has at least two elements. But its type only promises that it has at least one; useful information has been discarded.
3. From a social perspective, folks are scared enough of Cabal Hell to avoid pulling in extra dependencies just to deal with "non-empty things". When you want to work with monads-sans-`return` and categories-sans-`id`, installing the [`semigroupoids`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids) package requires a chunk of the "Kmett Platform".

Comment: #2 isn't clear. It seems to imply that if `xs` and `ys` are only `Semigroup` values, we lose information that we would retain if they were `Monoid` values instead.

Comment: @chepner Let me try to rephrase that: I'm trying to say that the semigroup operation `a -> a -> a` is imprecise when applied to certain types such as non-empty lists. The semigroup operation just makes more sense when the type with which it's used happens to have a zero. Appending lists to get a list is a more natural operation than appending non-empty lists to get a non-empty list

Answer (score 3):

It's the same as with all the other abstractions: the more operations you have at your disposal, the more complex things you can abstract over. Concerning `Monoid` specifically, here are a few most popular functions, which `Semigroup` is just not enough for:

```
foldMap :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m

fold :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => t m -> m

mconcat :: Monoid a => [a] -> a
```